# Drupal Commerce 2 add to cart form in Search API view

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to add an add to cart form over my thumbnails in a search api view. So far I have managed to use a twig template for a view mode of my product in the Search API view. What code do i need to add in twig to have the add to cart form working correctly for each product displayed?

Here is where the idea is coming from [Acromedia Demo](https://commerce.acromedia.com/).

Their /products page is a search API view with facets looks and works great but I wish I had also the add to cart form over the thumbnail.

The way they declare their view is very simple you have to create a Search API Index for Products declare it, as an unformatted list of rendered entity and set teaser view mode in settings. Then if you override the twig template for products as in [here](https://github.com/AcroMedia/commerce-demo/blob/master/web/themes/custom/commerce_2_demo/templates/commerce/commerce-product.html.twig) you get the corresponging html under the twig comment {# Product teaser. #}.

Copying from their example I also used the below hooks but:

```
function gavias_owl_preprocess_views_view( &$variables ) {

  // Get view mode & assign variable.
  if ($variables['id'] == 'products_catalog') $variables['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
}

/**
* Implements hook_preprocess(&$variables, $hook).
*/

function gavias_owl_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Commerce Product.
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#entity_type']) && $hook == 'commerce_product') {
    if (isset($variables['elements']['#commerce_product'])) {
      // Set base path variable.
      $variables['base_path'] = base_path();
      // Get view mode & assign variable.
      $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
      $variables['view_mode'] = $view_mode;

      // Get product and variations.
      $product = $variables['elements']['#commerce_product'];
      $product_variations = $product->getVariations();

      // Product Images.
      if (isset($product->field_image->entity)) {
        // Create array to feed images into.
        $product_images = [];
      }
      if (isset($product->field_image->entity)) {
        foreach ($product->field_image as $key => &$product_image) {
          $product_images[$key]['variation_id'] = '';
          $product_images[$key]['images'][$key] = $product_image;
        }
      }

      // Product Variation Images.
      if (!empty($product_variations)) {
        // Loop through variations and create array to feed images
        // if the variation is active and contains an image.
        foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {
          if ($variation->status->value == '1') {
            if (isset($variation->field_image->entity)) {
              // Create array to feed images into.
              $product_variation_images = [];
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        foreach ($product_variations as $key => $variation) {
          // If variation is active.
          if ($variation->status->value == '1') {
            // If variation has an image.
            if (isset($variation->field_image->entity)) {
              $variation_id = $variation->variation_id->value;
              $product_variation_images[$key]['variation_id'] = $variation_id;

              foreach ($variation->field_image as $image_key => &$variation_image) {
                $product_variation_images[$key]['images'][$image_key] = $variation_image;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Set product images variable combining both product images and variation images.
      if (isset($product_images) && isset($product_variation_images)) {
        $variables['product_variation_images'] = 
        array_merge($product_variation_images, $product_images);
      }
      elseif (isset($product_variation_images)) {
        $variables['product_variation_images'] = $product_variation_images;
      }
      elseif (isset($product_images)) {
        $variables['product_variation_images'] = $product_images;
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_commerce_product_variation(&$variables).
 */
function gavias_owl_preprocess_commerce_product_variation(&$variables) {
  // Commerce Product Variation.
  if (isset($variables['elements']['#commerce_product_variation'])) {
    // Get view mode & assign variable.
    $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];
    $variables['view_mode'] = $view_mode;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, could you add a little more to your question? Maybe what you’ve tried so far? Hooks and such?

Comment: subscribe to @Prestosaurus question. May be screenshots would be helpful?

Comment: @Prestosaurus I have edited my answer to give some more hints. The example I am showing of cource it is a view of products and not a products variation  view where an add to cart button could work

Comment: @pv1, Have you find any solution for this issue. I am also stuck in this not able to add and "add to cart" button in search API view.
If you have any ideas I will appreciate it to share.